# Balanced Distribution Of Items

Tags: algorithms

I shall call this the "Curtain Hook" problem.

Please excuse my lack of formal maths notation as it has been over 20 years since I have needed it.

A standard pencil pleat curtain has L number of loops on the back (evenly spaced along the width) with which to hang the curtain.  The curtain pole will come with H number of hoops to hang the curtain upon.
The problem is how to distribute - with as uniform as possible gaps between - the hooks across the loops.

For example, if I have 15 hooks (per curtain) and each curtain has 38 loops where should I hang the 15 hooks?

By hand I came up with:
HoHooHooHooHoHooHooHoHooHooHoHooHooHoH
Which is not evenly spaced. (H being a hook, o being an unused loop)

Is there an evenly balanced solution for this combination?
Is there an algorithm that can be used to describe where to place the hooks evenly?

Ps. Not homework, just someone with a curious analytical mind who had to put up some curtains recently.  I was thinking of creating a web page to help others if a general solution/algorithm could be found.

Thanks

Craig

Comment: We cannot solve your problem until you clearly define it. What objective function are you trying to optimize? When would you consider one solution better than another? What is an "evenly balanced solution"?

Comment: Once you define your problem properly, the solution will likely be very simple. This question might fit better in math.se.

Comment: Okay I agree my definition is not great, by "evenly" perhaps the best terms I could try are "with some pattern of symmetry or repetition" whilst retaining a minimal variance in the size of gap. For example gaps 2's and 1's would be okay but gaps of 2's and 6's would not.

Comment: I also agree maths.se may be the best place for it but all my searches for similar questions led me here, so I thought I would try here first. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't quite defined your problem, so let me answer a more concrete one: when can there be an evenly spaced solution. I assume that by "evenly spaced" you mean that all the spaces are the same, and that there must be hooks and the first and last positions. If the space is $s$, then we must have
$$ L = 1 + (s+1)(H-1), $$
since the string is of the form $H(o^sH)^{H-1}$. This is possible if and only if $H-1$ divides $L-1$, in which case the spacing is
$$
 s = \frac{L-1}{H-1} - 1.
$$
In your case, 14 doesn't divide 37, so an even spacing is impossible.

Comment: The gaps may vary, but by as little as possible. E.g. HooHoooHooH would be fine but HoHoooooHoH would not.

Comment: I fear that getting a computer or algorithm to recognise my definition of a pattern may be beyond the scope of this question